# The same message appears when I type `yes` in the loop

Tags: python

When I enter `yes` to repeat the game, then instead of repeating, this message appears:

> do you want to play again (yes or no):

This only happens when I enter `yes`. But if I enter `no`, then it exits from the game.

#### Code I have

```
print('                                    Welcome to the gussing game :)')
print("\n\nyou have only 3 attempts to win ")

hidden_word = 'zak'
guess_word = ''
count_attempts = 0
limit_attempts = 3
play_again = 'yes'


while play_again == 'yes':
    while (guess_word != hidden_word) and (count_attempts < limit_attempts):
        guess_word = input("\nplease enter your word: ")
        count_attempts += 1
        if count_attempts == limit_attempts and guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Sorry,  you lose due to Out of attempts ")
        elif guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Wrong attempt, try again ...")
        #Remember that {the order of the if statments is imporatnt and can change your result to be the unwanted one }
        else:
            print(" Wow you won !!")
    play_again = input('\ndo you want to play again (yes or no): ').lower()
```

#### Question

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great you added a [example]. What is your question? Please be specific and [edit] your question, put in a question phrasing what you expect, what you want, or where you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't reset the value of your variable, `guess_word` and `count_attempts`. Therefore, `while (guess_word != hidden_word) and (count_attempts < limit_attempts):` is always false in your second iteration onwards, and the inner while loop is skipped.

You can reset the value before the inner while loop.

```py
while play_again == 'yes':
    guess_word = ''
    count_attempts = 0
    while (guess_word != hidden_word) and (count_attempts < limit_attempts):
        guess_word = input("\nplease enter your word: ")
        count_attempts += 1
        if count_attempts == limit_attempts and guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Sorry,  you lose due to Out of attempts ")
        elif guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Wrong attempt, try again ...")
        #Remember that {the order of the if statments is imporatnt and can change your result to be the unwanted one }
        else:
            print(" Wow you won !!")
    play_again = input('\ndo you want to play again (yes or no): ').lower()
```

Comment: Could you please calrify why when we put the variables inside the loop it has been reset unlike the old ones when they were outside the loop? @wavetitan

Comment: There are 2 while loops here. At the end of the outer while loop, you asked the user to input play_again. Then, it will go back to the condition of the outer while loop `play_again == 'yes'`. If it is true, the user goes through the second iteration of the outer loop. The user should start at a fresh start before starting the guess (which is the inner while loop). Therefore, you reset the `guess_word` and `count_attempts` before the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that after the user enters "yes", you need to set `guess_word` back to an empty string and reset `count_attempts`, otherwise the inner while loop conditional check is already false. In a final implementation you would also reset the hidden word at this time as well.

The simplest solution would be to move almost all of the setup code inside of the outer while loop

```
limit_attempts = 3
play_again = 'yes'


while play_again == 'yes':
    print('                                    Welcome to the gussing game :)')
    print("\n\nyou have only 3 attempts to win ")

    hidden_word = 'zak'
    guess_word = ''
    count_attempts = 0
    while (guess_word != hidden_word) and (count_attempts < limit_attempts):
        guess_word = input("\nplease enter your word: ")
        count_attempts += 1
        if count_attempts == limit_attempts and guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Sorry,  you lose due to Out of attempts ")
        elif guess_word != hidden_word:
            print("Wrong attempt, try again ...")
        #Remember that {the order of the if statments is imporatnt and can change your result to be the unwanted one }
        else:
            print(" Wow you won !!")
    play_again = input('\ndo you want to play again (yes or no): ').lower()
```